# How should I setup Drush to work with Drupal 8.8.1 using Git Bash on Windows 10

Tags: 8, drush

I am using a Windows computer and using Git Bash, I just installed a new 8.8.1 site and also did 'composer require drush/drush'. I can't use Drush from anywhere so I am wondering if I should have installed Drush globally on the computer.

Comment: what do you use locally: xampp, wampp or damp (drupal acquia dev desktop) ?

Comment: Yes, because it lives in the vendor directory and CLI does not know what you mean as just `drush`, so you'd have to use the launcher/wrapper, or refer to it by path like `../../vendor/bin/drush (command)...`

Comment: @Nathan I am using WAMP, meanwhile I got it to work by using its path as `../vendor/bin/drush {command}` I also have Acquia Dev Desktop installed but for some reasons I need to use WAMP this time. ADD has Drush bundled and works seamlessly in Windows.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I will use its path as it will suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't install Drush globally anymore. You install the [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) instead. It will provide you a global `drush` command that automagically uses the local Drush from each project.

> ## Drush Launcher
>
> A small wrapper around Drush for your global $PATH.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx but I will actually prefer to have Drush per project, I won't mind moving into any folder within each project to run it. But in this case, having ran 'composer require drush/drush' I can't use Drush from any folder within the project.

Comment: @Chike – You have Drush per project. And then you have Drush Launcher to launch each project's Drush when you somewhere in your project type `$ drush cr` or whatever. So instead of typing `$ ../../../vendor/bin/drush cr` or similar the Drush Launcher will do that for you.

Comment: I just found it in the path ../vendor/bin/drush It's Version 10.1.1. Trying to use `drush updb` or `drush cr` throws this error `Command drush was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. As a r esult, many commands are unavailable. Re-run your command with --debug to see relevant log messages.`

Comment: running drush --debug shows this `Exception trace:
  at C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\drush\drush\src\Application.php:239
 Drush\Application->bootstrapAndFind() at C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\drush\drush\src\Application.php:192
 Drush\Application->find() at C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:236
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at `

Comment: `C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php:118
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php:49
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php:72
 require() at C:\wamp64\www\folder\vendor\drush\drush\drush:4`

Comment: Seems that's a completely new question then, innit?

Comment: Sorry it's my bad, I was issuing `./vendor/bin/drush drush {command}` instead of `./vendor/bin/drush {command}` thus overloading the commands. It works as designed, it's all my fault. Thanks.